# Hbase data deleted upon restart

Tags: java, hbase

I'm not sure what's happening. I created table yesterday in hbase using the following code.

I start hbase using this command.

`hbase-2.0.0/bin$ ./start-hbase.sh`

Code to create table

```
private void createStudentTable(String workspace) {
        List<ColumnFamilyDescriptor> colms = new ArrayList<>();
        colms.add(ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder.of("id"));
        colms.add(ColumnFamilyDescriptorBuilder.of("name"));


        TableDescriptor desc = TableDescriptorBuilder.newBuilder(TableName.valueOf(workspace + "_an_data"))
                  .setColumnFamilies(colms)
                  .build();

        hbaseAdmin.createTable(desc); //class variable 
    }
```

I shutdown hbase using command

```
hbase-2.0.0/bin$ ./stop-hbase.sh
```

Turned off my system, next day woke up, start hbase.

Login to shell, running `list` command result it

```
TABLE                                                                           
0 row(s)
```

Am I misunderstanding something? hbase is not file memory database? Is it in-memory?

I used phoenix driver in DBeaver same behavior

Comment: even though with that hbase-site.xml you are having problem?

Comment: No @Deadpool I didn't know that hbase using /tmp folder. That's so wired. Once I configure data directory, now working fine.

Comment: you can check this quick start document, they mentioned clearly https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart

Answer (score 2):

By default the hbase.rootdir is in /tmp which is cleaned up every time you reboot. Update the hbase-site.xml to use a directory of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

To give an example for @gagan's answer

Config File: `/hbase-2.0.0/conf/hbase-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/pasu/apps/hbase-2.0.0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/pasu/apps/hbase-2.0.0/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.unsafe.stream.capability.enforce</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```